# Service Principal Details json

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

The process of Service Principal creation in my organisation is automated. This means, I cannot create one via azure cli. So, I am unable to copy the json that gets generated during Service Principal creation. I need this json to be kept as github actions secret to establish a connection with Keyvault from my pipeline. I understand I can reset the Service principal password from Azure portal - ie; from certificates and secrets -> new client secret. I have three questions:

(1) Is the below json sample the same as the one that gets generated while creating Service Principal via command line
(2) If yes, can I use the secret value which I reset from the portal?
(3) What is the tenant id?

```
{
  "appId": "...",
  "displayName": "",
  "password": "...",
  "tenant": "..."
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Correct ! When we create the serviceprincipal using command:
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n spname , output will be displayed in below format:

{

"appId": "id",

"displayName": "nameofsp",

"password": "pwd",

"tenant": "subscription tenant id"

}

You can use the secret value when you reset from Azure Portal !

TenantID is nothing but under which your subscription is there...

How to find TenantID of the sub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace/find-tenant-object-id